# JS/Express Send a very big string to an express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What is the best way to send a very big String to a nodeJs express server?
I have a Webpage with [codemirror](https://codemirror.net/) which is able to load files from a express server and load them into Codemirror.
But what method is the best to send "the file"(actually it's a string,can be realy big)
back to the express api ?

Comment: multipart uploads are often used to send files. You can use `multer` to manage it in the server

Comment: You can do so with just a POST request and the string as the body of the POST.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to stream the data instead of sending everything at the same time. I don't know how to do that on the client side, I actually don't think that to stream a request is even possible.

I'm not an expert and I don't know much about large strings, but why is that a problem? From a networking point of vue, isn't the TCP protocol supposed to packet everything?